# Fixed points of Frobenius

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $X$ be a scheme over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $F$ the Frobenius morphism. I want to understand why $X(\mathbb{F}_q)$ are the fixed points of $F$ on $X(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q)$.

Edit. Is the following correct?
[image: my thoughts]

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? In general, this is because $X$ is a sheaf for the étale topology? Since you tagged this as étale cohomology, I'll assume you know what that means. Namely, to be a sheaf on $(\text{Spec}(k)_\text{et})$ is the same as requiring that the natural map $F(K)\to F(L)^{\text{Gal}(L/K)}$ is an isomorphism for all $L/K$ finite Galois. Your question then follows since every $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$-point factors through a finite Galois extension and the fact that $X$ is a sheaf. In much simpler terms, have you tried just messing around with it?

Comment: The data of an $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$-point is the data of a point $x\in X$ and an embedding $k(x)\hookrightarrow\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$. To say that this embedding is fixed by the Galois action says precisely that the image is Galois invariant which, of course, implies that its image lies in $\mathbb{F}_q$ so that it's a $\mathbb{F}_q$-point.

Comment: My question actually came up while reading an introduction (better motivation) for étale cohomology. There is still a little confusion: In your first comment you mention that one needs to work with étale topology in order to proof the statement, right? But I don't see where I'm missing that piece in my edit above.